# How to update MS Access table with a letter sequence dependent on the number of instances other record fields appear

Tags: sql, vba, database, ms-access

I'm developing a tool database in MS Access and the tool numbering convention is some area code followed by the assembly letter (written as assembly number in the table). The combination of the area code and assembly letter creates the key for each record. Essentially what I want to happen is for each time an area code is repeated, another letter is permanently assigned to the assembly letter field. for instance, If I have an area code "7474", and it's the first instance of 7474 in the table, the letter "A" is assigned to it and the combination key is "7474 A". If I enter the second instance of "7474", then "B" populates the second record's assembly letter field. If I then enter a new area code of "6852", "A" should populate its assembly letter field. I'll only ever be adding one record at a time, so I use the placeholder "-" to indicate that this is a record that needs to be updated. I'm currently running an update query which will work as long as there is a single area code in the records, as soon as I add another area code I develop key violations. I cannot add "A" manually for the same reason, despite the combination being unique. Its acting as if the assembly letter is the primary key for the record.

When I run the below code, it will correctly count the instance of each area code and output the resulting next available letter for each. It just won't assign the result to an area code if the resulting letter already appears elsewhere.

**This is the SQL code I use:**

```
UPDATE [Tool Table] 
SET [Tool Table].[ASSEMBLY NUMBER] = CalculateAssemblyNumber([AREA CODE])
WHERE ((([Tool Table].[ASSEMBLY NUMBER]) Is Null Or ([Tool Table].[ASSEMBLY NUMBER])='-'));
```

**This is the VBA code I use:**

```
Function CalculateAssemblyNumber(AreaCode As Variant) As String
   Dim countMatch As Integer

    Debug.Print "AreaCode: " & AreaCode

    countMatch = DCount("*", "[Tool Table]", "[AREA CODE] = '" & AreaCode & "'")

    Debug.Print "CountMatch: " & countMatch

    CalculateAssemblyNumber = Chr(64 + countMatch)

    Debug.Print "Result: " & CalculateAssemblyNumber
End Function
```

Comment: So you want to be limited to 26 sequential records for each area? If table won't allow duplication of a letter by manual input, how would you expect any code to accomplish that? What is it about table design that doesn't allow duplicate letter? How have you defined primary key? Have you set area and letter fields as a compound index?

Answer (score 0):

I guess your problem is that the assembly field is set to be unique. When you build your record key out of two fields, none of the fields must be unique, just the key itself. Check this and your problem should be solved.
Another question is how to handle cases where you are already have the assembly letter "Z". What you will do then?